# How to set the background color to transparent in Asymptote (in a LaTeX file)?

Tags: asymptote, backgrounds, transparency

I'm trying to draw an `Asymptote` image in a `LaTeX` file. I want the background of the image to be transparent (to see the page color). How do I do? I use `pdflatex`.

In the MWE I draw a sphere and the background is a square. If I don't set the background color then it is white and if I set it, it is black (the `opacity` doesn't works). I also tried to set `render=0`. In that case it works, but the overall appearance is bad.

I am not very experienced with `Asymptote` and I have never use it outside of `LaTeX`. I don't know if it is related to `LaTeX` and/or `Asymptote`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagecolor{gray}  
\begin{center}
\begin{asy}
import graph3;
import solids;
//settings.render=0;  
size(16cm,0);
pen backgroundpen = black+opacity(0); 
pen spColor = RGB(22,104,204);
currentlight=light(background=backgroundpen, diffuse=white, dir(1,1));
surface sp = surface(sphere(1));
material m=material(diffusepen=spColor, emissivepen=spColor);  
draw(sp, m, render(merge=true));
\end{asy}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not going to be doable with 3d graphics unless `render=0`. (Which as you say usually looks bad.) Sorry.